# Log4j Not Writing Log File

Tags: java, log4j

I am attempting to log using my Java Web Aaplication for the first time using ServletContext. I am not getting Any Log files. Can someone tell me what I am not doing Right?

My ServletContextListener:

```
@Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {

        ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
        String prefix = context.getRealPath("/");
        String file = "WEB-INF" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "classes" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "log4j.properties";

        if (file != null) {
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(prefix + file);
            System.out.println("Log4J Logging started for application: " + prefix + file);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Log4J Is not configured for application Application: " + prefix + file);
        }
    }
```

My Web.xml:

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>com.kollega.listener.KollegaContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.logger.kollegalogger=DEBUG, C, fileappender
log4j.appender.fileappender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileappender.File=/WEB-INF/logs/kollega.log
log4j.appender.fileappender.MaxFileSize=500KB
```

My Test Servlet:

```
private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("kollegalogger");
log.debug(">>> Connectition TO database Successful for Login");
        Logger.getLogger(LoginServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.FATAL, ">>>>Connectition TO database Successful for Login");
```

Am Only Getting the Output for DEBUG but there is no Log file in WEB-INF/logs/kollega.log. Any thing I am missing?

**EDIT:**
**I removed ${appRootPath} from the File Path and the Log is Getting Created in C:/WEB-INF/logs/kollega.log. I need it in My WEB-INF Directory**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out. Paths in web application works relative to `/WEB-INF` and not `WEB-INF`

```
String file = System.getProperty("file.separator")+"WEB-INF" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "classes" + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "log4j.properties";
```

Comment: I still do not have Any log file in the WEB-INF folder. I am using Netbeans. :(

Comment: /WEB-INF is context folder in your web application

Comment: Are you telling me there is no way the File is going to get writen in that Folder? If then how Can I Write it Outside the WEB-INF folder but inside the Application Folder?

Comment: Of course logs can be written to outside folder of application (or server). But real problem in above case is application is not able to locate log4j.properties file.

Comment: Is that why it is writing The log File in C:/WEB-INF???? And I am getting this output from my debug `Log4J Logging started for application: C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Kollega\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\log4j.properties` So I think the Properties file can be Found.

Answer (score 0):

Place the properties file in the classpath where your class files are or in `WEB-INF/classes`, then you can just load it easily as follows:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");**
```